# Scrpay - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'http.client'

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, scrapy, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Django project and inside the Django project, there is a Scrapy spider.

```
django_project/manage.py
              /spider/spider/settings.py
              /spider/spider/spiders/myspider.py
```

I've activated environment this way:

```
source /opt/python/current/env (According to the tutorial)
source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate
```

and cd to `django_project/spider` - like on my computer.

When I try to do:

```
 /opt/python/run/venv/bin/python3.6 /opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py crawl spider
```

It returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 8, in <module>
    import scrapy
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from twisted import version as _txv
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from twisted.python.deprecate import deprecatedModuleAttribute
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/python/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .compat import unicode
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/python/compat.py", line 605, in <module>
    from http import cookiejar as cookielib
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/http/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from scrapy.http.headers import Headers
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/http/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from scrapy.http.request import Request
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/http/request/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from w3lib.url import safe_url_string
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/w3lib/url.py", line 18, in <module>
    from six.moves.urllib.request import pathname2url, url2pathname
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 92, in __get__
    result = self._resolve()
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 160, in _resolve
    module = _import_module(self.mod)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 82, in _import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 88, in <module>
    import http.client
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'http.client'
```

Do you know where is the problem?

EDIT3:

```
ls -la /opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 ec2-user ec2-user 5364 30. srp 10.33 /opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py
```

So I changed it:

```
 chmod +x /opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py

-rwxr-xr-x 1 ec2-user ec2-user 5364 30. srp 10.33 cmdline.py
```

And now it returns the same error (http.client)...

Comment: "Permission denied" means your user lacks read or execute access. How did you copy the files into place and what are their permissions? `ls -l` to display, `chmod` to change them. This is a common beginner FAQ.

Comment: In fact, I used EBS cli to deploy the Django project. It is possible that I don't have permissions but I tried sudo chown ec2-user -R  /opt/python/run/venv/ which didn't help.

Comment: The error message you get are for the permissions to the `cmdline.py` script; that's the one whose permissions you need to adjust. Why are you using `sudo` at all here and, again, what exactly are the current permissions?

Comment: @tripleee Thank you, I tried to change permissions but it didn't help (maybe I do something wrong - I've added the permissions and commands to the bottom of the question). I tried sudo because of the permissions before.

Comment: -rwxr-xr-x   1 ec2-user ec2-user  5364 30. srp 10.33 cmdline.py

Comment: If you are still running it with `sudo` I'm guessing that's why it doesn't find the library. Is `http.client` installed in the virtual env? I'm hesitant to reopen this while you are moving the goalposts; probably still a duplicate but try to focus on one question at a time and we'll find a good dupliate.

Comment: I'll reduce this question to the 'http.client' problem. No, I'm running it this way: ` /opt/python/run/venv/bin/python3.6 /opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py crawl spider`

Comment: @tripleee I'm afraid that changing permissions didn't help.